# How does event-loop occur in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Nodejs is known to be best for simplification by "single thread". As I know, this single thread handles requests through a event loop. I want to ask:

Is Nodejs really only have one thread only? For example, if there is a billion users on a website, the thread will loop through a billion times? Or in fact there are some "small threads" that the large single thread will use to do different stuffs?

Thank you!